# I get Undefined Value When Tracing A variable Loaded from a text file in flash as2

Tags: flash, variables, actionscript-2, undefined

I'm using Swishmax 4 and I want to load a variable from an external txt file from flash.
I've created a dynamic text to load my variable. It worked well, but when I want to trace the variable I get an *undefined value*. Here is my code:

**file.txt**

```
&cont=data
```

**Code**

```
onFrame (1) {
    this.loadVariables("file.txt");
    trace(cont); // i get an undefined value here
}
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why, but I modify the script to this and its debugged correctly

```
onSelfEvent (load) {
    this.loadVariables("file.txt");
}
onFrame (3) {
    trace(cont);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't spec what's the content of that file.txt nor if it is in the same folder as the swf itself.
However, you should always take in consideration, that loading process takes some time, so you should not expect that code to work on remote severs (at least, not the first time you run the swf file). How can you be sure the file is loaded just before frame 0 (onLoad event)? In fact you can't.
On the second script you try to access the data a little bit later, so it is very possible the data has been loaded.

So you have to find a way to be sure the file is loaded OK, and you have a couple of ways doing this: using the loadVars class (recommended) or using another variable within the file.txt itself and check wheter its value is defined or not. An example of the 2nd method could be:

**file txt**

```
&myVar=Hello World!!&
&yourVar=finally there!!&
&yourAge=24&
&loadedDone=1&
```

**swi code:**

```
onSelfEvent(load){
  this.loadVariables("file.txt");
}
onFrame(2){
  if(loadedDone!= 1)prevFrameAndPlay(); // Wait till the file is loaded
}
onFrame(3){!!
  // Once the data is loaded, display variable values!!
  trace(myVar);
  trace(yourVar);
  trace(yourAge);
}
```

but this method has the problem that if the variable **loadeDone** is not defined or file.txt doesn't exist, your swi file will be stuck in an **endless loop**. So you should better give a try to loadVars class or use XML for this purpose.

Regards, cancrexo